# Licensing terms query

Tags: mysql

This is quite non technical question, but please help me with direction.

One of our customer who is enterprise (and quite nontechnical folks), is planning to buy a solution from us.  This solution can work on Linux or windows.  We are recommending them to use Ubuntu to save cost and great performance.  But they are worried about hidden licensing cost/impact if any. (We have given them ample examples that Ubuntu is free to use. But one competing agency which is Microsoft shop scaring them, and  I am die hard open source fan and don't want them to win.)

Is there Terms and Condition white paper for ubuntu, mySQL available which helps us to prove that Ubuntu/Linux is free to use in commercial environment also? (I know Amazon is the best example, but still it did not help!).

Regards,
VR

Comment: If in doubt with MySQL ---> MariaDB. It is a fork of MySQL led by its original developers and triggered by concerns over Oracle possibly "killing" MySQL. MariaDB will be free.

Comment: Ubuntu has no licensing problems, but I think you have to use MySQL Enterprise Edition if you want to *redistribute* MySQL with your solution (in case your solution is not open-source)

Answer (score 0):

This question is not necessarily about Ubuntu. Instead, it is about ALL open source software.

From the [official Open Source website](http://opensource.org/faq#commercial):

> Absolutely. All Open Source software can be used for commercial purpose; the Open Source Definition guarantees this. You can even sell Open Source software.
>
> However, note that commercial is not the same as proprietary. *If you receive software under an Open Source license, you can always use that software for commercial purposes*, but that doesn't always mean you can place further restrictions on people who receive the software from you. In particular, so-called copyleft-style Open Source licenses require that when you distribute the software, you do so under the same license you received it under.

(emphasis mine)

Ubuntu (well Linux) is *free software*. It can be used and redistributed for NO COST, regardless of what or where you are.

If you really wanted to, forward them a copy of the GPL.

Comment: I would add to that by suggesting you cover eventualities by supplying your solution with suitable disclaimers and acknowledgements where appropriate. If there is resistance from information provided by Windoze purveyors (or any 3rd party s/w house for that matter), point your Client in the direction of the disclaimers provided by Microsoft and others.